# Копирование файлов по маске из каталога, с сохранением иерархии папок

Tags: linux, bash

Задача звучит так:
Копирование группы файлов удовлетворяющих маске из одного каталога в другой (копировать подкаталоги). Маска и два других каталога передаются как параметры пакетного файла.

На данный момент есть код, который копирует файлы

```
find $1 -name "*.$2" -print0 |xargs --null cp --parents -t $3
```

Однако в результате получается, что в папке $3 находится папка Desktop, затем папка $1 и только потом содержимое, а нужно, чтобы сразу в папке $3 было содержимое. Как я понял, --parents хранит полный путь (могу ошибаться), поэтому и получается такая ерунда, но как это обойти я не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перейдите вначале в каталог-источник $1 и там выполняйте поиск файлов и копирование. Чтобы утилита **cp** смогла найти каталог-назначение $3, используется абсолютный путь.

```
dest=$(realpath "$3") &&
cd "$1" &&
find -name "*.$2" -print0 |
xargs -0r cp --parents -t "${dest}" --
```

Comment: а что значит xargs -0r и "--" в конце

Comment: `-0` — то же самое, что и `--null`, сокращение; `-r` — не выполнять команду, если ввод пустой, т.е. нет файлов с указанным расширением; `--` — конец опций для **cp**, чтобы она не восприняла случайно имя какого-то хитрого файла как свой параметр, это для надёжности

Comment: а `-0` и `-r` объединились в `-0r` для краткости